# Edit and save as a PDF in a folder based on Excel information

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, ms-word

Im having an issue, I have this Macro to make contracts, it reads the headers on my excel table where I have the information for the contracts (such as Salary, Name, branch offices) and replaces it in a word template.

Also creates a folder with name of the office where the employee works and saves the contratct as PDF with the employee name as filename; because I need to send them to their bosses.

But im having a problem, it does create all the Folders.. but it always ignores the first Branch office (I have them in alphabetical order) and then goes on fine with all the the others.
I ended up creating a new table, create a fake branch office to get the one I need saved.

Can you guys help me find the problem?

```
Sub CREAR_CARPETAS_X_UNIDAD()
Dim c, lRow As Long
Dim sCarpeta, sContratoModelo, sEmpresa, sNombreApellido, sUnidad As String
Dim sCarpetaUnidad As String
Dim sWord As Object

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim WordDoc As Object
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

t = Timer

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
sCarpeta = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
sContratoModelo = sCarpeta & "\CTS_NOVIEMBRE.docx"

'Create Folders for each unit
c = 2
Do
    On Error Resume Next
    sUnidad = UCase(Range("D" & c).Value)
    MkDir sCarpeta & "/" & sUnidad
    c = c + 1
Loop While Not c > lRow

'Copy Contract with the client name
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
c = 2
Do
    sUnidad = UCase(Range("D" & c).Value)
    sNombreApellido = UCase(Range("I" & c).Value)
    sCarpetaUnidad = sCarpeta & "/" & sUnidad
    
    WordApp.Visible = True
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(sContratoModelo)
    
    col = 1
    Do
        With WordDoc.Content.Find
          .Text = "OBJ_" & Cells(1, col).Value
          .Replacement.Text = Cells(c, col).Value
          .Wrap = wdFindContinue
          .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
        col = col + 1
    Loop While Not col > 31
            
    WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=sCarpetaUnidad & "\" & sNombreApellido & ".pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
    WordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    c = c + 1
Loop While Not c > lRow

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox ((Timer - t) & " segundos")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have a valid folder name for the first Branch office?

Your code could be simplified significantly:

```
Sub CREAR_CARPETAS_X_UNIDAD()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim c As Long, t As Single
Dim sCarpeta As String, sContratoModelo As String, sEmpresa As String
Dim sCarpetaUnidad As String, sNombreApellido As String, sUnidad As String
Dim WordApp As Word.Application, WordDoc As Word.Document

t = Timer
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True

sCarpeta = ActiveWorkbook.Path
sContratoModelo = sCarpeta & "\CTS_NOVIEMBRE.docx"

'Create Folders for each unit
For c = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    On Error Resume Next
    sUnidad = UCase(Range("D" & c).Value)
    MkDir sCarpeta & "/" & sUnidad

    'Copy Contract with the client name
    sNombreApellido = UCase(Range("I" & c).Value)
    sCarpetaUnidad = sCarpeta & "/" & sUnidad
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add(sContratoModelo)
    With WordDoc
        With .Content.Find
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            For col = 1 To 31
                .Text = "OBJ_" & Cells(1, col).Value
                .Replacement.Text = Cells(c, col).Value
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            Next
        End With
        .SaveAs Filename:=sCarpetaUnidad & "\" & sNombreApellido & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        .Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox ((Timer - t) & " segundos")
End Sub
```

You could also use an automated mailmerge. See *Run a Mailmerge from Excel, Sending the Output to Individual Files* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** page at:

https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

Comment: Oh, many thanks. The problem was the name, the data base had some branch office names with a blank space at the end. For the mailmerge, I use power automate because the administrators need to upload the documents scanned after the employee after they sign it, so is better for us to just send them a link to the folder on onedrive.